# What are the differences between 救う, 救助する and 助ける?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

From my understanding, 助ける{たすける} is used when helping someone with a task, 救助する{きゅうじょする} and 救う{すくう} can be used to save someone/something from a dangerous situation. However, 救う can also be used for the feelings (unlike 救助する).

Is it accurate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understand them mostly correctly.

助ける can be used for *help* in a broad sense, the difference from 救助する/救う is 助ける can mean *to assist*.

救う/救助する both mean *to save*, the latter sounds like the situation being more serious (e.g. fire, disaster). And as you noted, 救う can mean *consoled/consoling/feel less sad* (mostly) in the passive form 救われる. 救助する does not have this usage.